# retrieving multiple records from grandchild table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The following sql query is not working.

```
select UserName 
from [User] 
where UserID Like 
      ( select UserID 
        from UserRoles 
        where RoleID =
              ( select RoleID 
                from Roles 
                where RoleName='Manager'
              )
      )
```

Here we are working with 3 tables `User, UserRoles, Roles`. It shows the error as follows

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that a subquery is returning more than one row.

When you have a condition like `a = b` or one with `a LIKE b`, both sides should be one item. If either side is a subquery, care should be taken that the subquery always returns either 0 or 1 row (and never more than one).

You can rewrite with Joins or changing the `LIKE` and the `=` to `IN`:

```
select UserName 
from [User] 
where UserID IN                          --- LIKE replaced
      ( select UserID 
        from UserRoles 
        where RoleID IN                  --- equality (=) replaced
              ( select RoleID 
                from Roles 
                where RoleName = 'Manager'
              )
      ) ;
```

Comment: I think it's more likely the subquery after `LIKE` that is returning multiple results, but it's a good idea to use `IN` in both cases where the subqueries are being matched against.

Comment: @AndriyM: Yes, you are right. The *"or when the subquery is used as an expression: ..."* part of the error is relevant in this case. (I thought that `LIKE` would appear in the error message but it doesn't)

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about joins

```
SELECT UserName
FROM
     [User]
          inner join UserRoles on [User].UserID=UserRoles.UserID
          inner join Roles on UserRoles.RoleID=Roles.RoleID
WHERE
     RoleName='Manager'
```

Comment: +1 although there's a minor nitpick: I would probably put table aliases in front of `UserName` and `RoleName`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    UserName 
from 
    [User] as u 
inner join 
    (select UserID from UserRoles where RoleID in (select RoleID from Roles where RoleName='Manager'))
as t on u.userId like t.userid+%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  select U.UserName 
        from UserRoles UR join Roles R
        on UR.RoleID=R.RoleID
        join [User] U
        on U.UserID like '%'+UR.UserID+'%'
        where R.RoleName='Manager'
```